# Type agnostic, statically allocated, thread-safe queue in C

Tags: c, thread-safety, queue, embedded, variant-type

I need a queue in C for an embedded application in which I cannot allocate memory dynamically.

I avoided using `void*` for the queue elements (which is not convenient lifecycle-wise) by having the user provide their underlying array.

`user_code.c`:

```
#include "generic_queue.c"

typedef struct custom_t
{
    /* whatever */
} custom_t;

custom_t underlying_array[5];
queue_t queue;
queue_init(&queue, underlying_array, 5, sizeof(custom_t));
/* now use queue to do stuff */
queue_destroy(&queue);
```

`generic_queue.h`:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARD_GENERIC_QUEUE_H
#define INCLUDE_GUARD_GENERIC_QUEUE_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct queue_t
{
    void* array;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t sizeof_element;
    size_t in;
    size_t out;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} queue_t;


/* return true on success */
bool queue_init(queue_t* queue, void* array, size_t capacity, size_t sizeof_element);
void queue_destroy(queue_t* queue);
bool queue_front(queue_t * queue, void *dest);
bool queue_back(queue_t * queue, void *dest);
bool queue_push(queue_t *queue, void const *src);
bool queue_pop(queue_t *queue, void *dest);

/* assert on failure */
size_t queue_size(queue_t * queue);
size_t queue_capacity(queue_t * queue);
bool queue_empty(queue_t * queue);
bool queue_full(queue_t * queue);

#endif /* INCLUDE_GUARD_GENERIC_QUEUE_H */
```

`genric_queue.c`:

```
#include "generic_queue.h"

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h> /* memcpy */
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>


bool queue_init(queue_t* queue, void* array, size_t capacity, size_t sizeof_element)
{
    bool success;
    
    if ((queue == NULL) || (array == NULL) || (capacity < 2) || (sizeof_element == 0))
    {
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&queue->mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
        
        queue->array = array;
        queue->capacity = capacity;
        queue->sizeof_element = sizeof_element;
        queue->in = 0;
        queue->out = 0;
        success = true;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    }
    return success;
}

void queue_destroy(queue_t* queue)
{
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&queue->mutex);
   queue->array = NULL;
   queue->capacity = 0;
   queue->sizeof_element = 0;
   queue->in = 0;
   queue->out = 0;
}

static void* index_to_address(queue_t const * queue, size_t index)
{
    void* address;
    assert(queue != NULL);
    
    /* No mutex here: this is an internal utility function */
    address = ((unsigned char*)queue->array) + (index * queue->sizeof_element);
    
    return address;
}

static bool queue_empty_internal(queue_t * queue, bool lock_mutex)
{
    bool empty;
    assert(queue != NULL);
    
    if (lock_mutex) { pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex); }
    empty = (queue->in == queue->out);
    if (lock_mutex) { pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex); }
    
    return empty;
}

bool queue_empty(queue_t * queue)
{
    return queue_empty_internal(queue, true);
}

/* When used internally, mutex might be already locked, so an additional "private" `lock_mutex` argument is needed */
static bool queue_front_internal(queue_t * queue, void *dest, bool lock_mutex)
{
    bool success;
    void *src;
    
    if ((queue == NULL) || (queue_empty_internal(queue, lock_mutex)) || (dest == NULL))
    {
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (lock_mutex) { pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex); }
        
        src = index_to_address(queue, queue->out);
        memcpy(dest, src, queue->sizeof_element);
        success = true;
        
        if (lock_mutex) { pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex); }
    }
    return success;
}

bool queue_front(queue_t * queue, void *dest)
{
    return queue_front_internal(queue, dest, true);
}

bool queue_back(queue_t * queue, void *dest)
{
    bool success;
    size_t index;
    void *src;
    
    if ((queue == NULL) || (queue_empty(queue)) || (dest == NULL))
    {
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
        
        index = (queue->in == 0) ? queue->capacity - 1 : queue->in - 1;
        src = index_to_address(queue, index);
        memcpy(dest, src, queue->sizeof_element);
        success = true;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    }
    return success;
}

bool queue_push(queue_t *queue, void const *src)
{
    bool success;
    void *dest;
    
    if ((queue == NULL) || (queue_full(queue)) || (src == NULL))
    {
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
        
        dest = index_to_address(queue, queue->in);
        memcpy(dest, src, queue->sizeof_element);
        queue->in = (queue->in + 1) % queue->capacity;
        success = true;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    }
    return success;
}

bool queue_pop(queue_t *queue, void *dest)
{
    bool success;
    
    if ((queue == NULL) || (queue_empty(queue)))
    {
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
        
        if (dest != NULL)
        {
            queue_front_internal(queue, dest, false);
        }
        queue->out = (queue->out + 1) % queue->capacity;
        success = true;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    }
    return success;
}

size_t queue_size(queue_t * queue)
{
    size_t size;
    assert(queue != NULL);
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
    
    if (queue->out <= queue->in)
    {
        size = queue->in - queue->out;
    }
    else
    {
        size = queue->in + queue->capacity - queue->out;
    }
    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    
    return size;
}

size_t queue_capacity(queue_t * queue)
{
    size_t capacity;
    assert(queue != NULL);
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
    capacity = queue->capacity - 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    
    return capacity;
}

bool queue_full(queue_t * queue)
{
    bool full;
    assert(queue != NULL);
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
    full = (((queue->in + 1) % queue->capacity) == queue->out);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
    
    return full;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but VTC. This question is not about a code review, but a design review. It likely belong to SO. That said, there are quite a few design flaws here.

Comment: I think if the full implementations were shown this could be brought on-topic.

Comment: @vnp implementation added.

Comment: @vnp Refactored. I think now it is less of a design review and more of a code review.

Comment: What's your target system that does support pthreads but doesn't allow heap allocation? Doesn't sound like any existing system out there. Pthread = POSIX threads, POSIX = Portable (hosted) Operating System Interface. There exist no hosted OS that doesn't allow heap allocation. So what you really need is to review the requirement spec that lead you to write this code, before anything else.

Comment: @Lundin the limitation comes from coding standards for safety critical applications, not the target system itself.

Comment: @Sparkler Okay...  Now as it turns out, coding standards for safety-critical applications happens to be one of my areas of expertise. The majority of the libs you use here are outright banned from safety critical applications. Pthreads are also very unlikely to be allowed. This code overall doesn't look particularly MISRA-C compliant. And generic programming is a complete no-go in safety-critical systems, they need to be 100% deterministic. So overall you need consider if this code should actually be used for safety-critical applications or just for some manner of PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks quite nice. I especially like that you have a very consistent API with clear names that follow the conventions of the C++ STL, and the pointer to the queue always as the first parameter. That said, there are some possible improvements.

## Naming things

I would use `queue_init()` and `queue_exit()` here. Alternatively, use `queue_create()` and `queue_destroy()`, however I would use those names only if those actually allocated/freed a `queue_t`.

Instead of `sizeof_element` I would write write `element_size`, or perhaps just `size`, as the latter is already used in a similar way in standard C functions like [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

I would also use `head` and `tail` instead of `in` and `out`.

## Be consistent using `if` or `assert()`

Some functions use an `if`-statement to check if parameters are valid, others just use `assert()`. Be consistent and always use the same method for a given parameter, like `queue`. And also make sure that if one function checks it, all of them. For example, `queue_destroy()` fails to check whether `queue` is `NULL`.

I advice you to use `assert()` for catching programming errors, and `if`-statements to catch runtime errors. I would consider `queue` being `NULL` a programming error. However, trying to insert into a full queue would be a runtime error, since what we put into a queue is most likely something we did not know up front when writing the program. The exception would be `queue_destroy()`, where I would use an `if`-statement to check for `NULL`, as this matches what `free()` does.

Did you consider checking the return value of `pthread_mutex_init()` and `pthread_mutex_lock()`? It so happens that in your code, you can avoid checking that, since you are not using recursive mutexes, but if you didn't know that, you should have either written `if`-statements to check whether these functions succeeded, or have read their manual pages to check whether they could fail.

## Handle corner cases if possible

While it seems rather silly, there is no reason not to allow a queue of size 0 or 1, and elements of size 0. Handling corner cases correctly makes your code more robust.

Related to this:

## Allow the whole queue to be used

You allow one less element in the queue than the capacity you pass to `queue_init()`. In fact:

```
int array[10];
queue_t queue;
queue_init(&queue, array, 10, sizeof(int));
int capacity = queue_capacity(queue); // will be 9!
```

Most likely you did this to work around the ambiguity when `in == out`. However, you can work around this by not having two indices into the array, but rather one offset and one count of the number of elements in the queue.

## Use `const` whereever it is possible

You should mark parameters as `const` whenever it is possible to do so. For example, `queue_empty()` does not modify the queue at all, so the parameter `queue` should be a `const queue_t *`.

## Avoid locking the mutex unnecessarily

There is no need to lock the mutex in `queue_capacity()`, as the capacity should never change between `queue_init()` and `queue_destroy()`.

## Make a clear distinction between locked and unlocked functions

Instead of having a `queue_empty_internal()` that takes a parameter whether to lock the mutex or not, I would write a `queue_empty_unlocked()` that never locks, and then make sure `queue_empty()` takes the lock itself before calling `queue_empty_unlocked()`. I would make it so that all user visible API functions take the lock, and all internal functions not take locks.

## Consider returning a pointer instead of copying an element

Instead of `queue_front()` returning a `bool` and copying the contents to `dest`, I would rather have it return a pointer to the front element, or return `NULL` if the queue is empty. This is especially useful if the elements are very large, or if you want to modify an element that is in the queue.

Comment: "use head and tail instead of in and out" --> "in" and "out" is quite clear.  With "head/tail" food goes in near head come out near tail or was it the head of the line is the eldest in the queue and next to come out and stuff goes in the tail or ...

Comment: I had to remove the const because of the mutex

Answer (score 2):

Not much to add to the good code and the good review of [@G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255115/29485)

**No error checking of `pthread_mutex...()` calls**

I'd expect return values checked.

**Consider an `apply()` function**

Consider a function that applies a function to each queue element.  Maybe ending early if an error detected.

```
bool queue_apply(queue_t * queue, int (*apply)(void *state, void *ellement), void * state);
```

Useful for printing and others tasks.

**Some functional documentation in the `*.h`**

Consider a user should get an idea of code use just by looking at the .h file.  Example: It is unclear what the below do.  I recommend at least a one line descripting for each function and an over description for the set.

```
bool queue_front(queue_t * queue, void *dest);
bool queue_back(queue_t * queue, void *dest);
```

**Alternative style**

Consider this style  [order of parameters in function declarations should be arranged such that the size of an array appears before the array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features)

```
// bool queue_init(queue_t* queue, void* array, size_t capacity, size_t sizeof_element);
bool queue_init(queue_t* queue, size_t capacity, void* array, size_t sizeof_element);
```